# How to get results from join only if all records match

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem to make an SQL query. I have two tables named `'loans'` and `'loan_emilists'`

[image: loan table]

[image: loan_emitlist table]

I want to fetch loan id from first table i.e 'loans' where loan.emilists table status have all 1.

**For example:-**

Loan id = 1 Because in the 2nd table i.e. 'loan_emilists' loan_id = 1 have all status value 1.

**MySQL Query:-**

> SELECT DISTINCT(loans.id) FROM `loans` LEFT JOIN loan_emilists ON
>   loans.id = loan_emilists.loan_id WHERE loan_emilists.status = 1

But it gives me both 1 and 2 loan.id.

Comment: Can you give me your expected output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use not exists() :

```
SELECT s.id FROM loans s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from loan_emilists t
                 where s.id = t.loan_id 
                   and t.status = 0)
```

This will work in case there is always a row in loan_emilists for each id in loans, if not you need to join, and then use not exists() :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id FROM loans s
INNER JOIN loan_emilists s1
 ON(s1.loan_id = s.id and s1.status = 1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from loan_emilists t
                 where s.id = t.loan_id 
                   and t.status = 0)
```

It can also be done with a left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id FROM loans s
INNER JOIN loan_emilists s1
 ON(s1.loan_id = s.id and s1.status = 1)
LEFT JOIN loan_emilists t
 ON(t.loan_id = s.id AND t.status = 0)
WHERE t.loan_id is null
```